# Zoom api gives error when I try to use refresh token

Tags: python, python-requests, access-token, refresh-token, zoom-sdk

We've been trying to get zoom refresh_token to work for months, but to no avail. Can anyone tell me where we're going wrong?

```
token = base64.b64encode(
    (getConfig().ZOOM_CLIENT_ID + ":" + getConfig().ZOOM_SECRET).encode('ascii'))
token = 'Basic ' + token.decode('UTF-8')

print('Token')
print(token)

result = session.post(f'https://zoom.us/oauth/token',
                      json={
                          'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
                          'refresh_token': refresh_token
                      }, 
                      headers={'Authorization': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

{'reason': 'unsupported grant type', 'error': 'unsupported_grant_type'}

The result should be something like this

```
{
   "access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInYiOiIyLjAiLCJraWQiOiI8S0lEPiJ9.eyJ2ZXIiOiI2IiwiY2xpZW50SWQiOiI8Q2xpZW50X0lEPiIsImNvZGUiOiI8Q29kZT4iLCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46em9vbTpjb25uZWN0OmNsaWVudGlkOjxDbGllbnRfSUQ-IiwiYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25JZCI6IjxBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbl9JRD4iLCJ1c2VySWQiOiI8VXNlcl9JRD4iLCJncm91cE51bWJlciI6MCwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9vYXV0aC56b29tLnVzIiwiYWNjb3VudElkIjoiPEFjY291bnRfSUQ-IiwibmJmIjoxNTgwMTQ3Mzk0LCJleHAiOjE1ODAxNTA5OTQsInRva2VuVHlwZSI6ImFjY2Vzc190b2tlbiIsImlhdCI6MTU4MDE0NzM5NCwianRpIjoiPEpUST4iLCJ0b2xlcmFuY2VJZCI6MjZ9.5c58p0PflZJdlz4Y7PgMIVCrQpHDnbM565iCKlrtajZ5HHmy00P5FCcoMwHb9LxjsUgbJ7653EfdeX5NEm6RoA",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInYiOiIyLjAiLCJraWQiOiI8S0lEPiJ9.eyJ2ZXIiOiI2IiwiY2xpZW50SWQiOiI8Q2xpZW50X0lEPiIsImNvZGUiOiI8Q29kZT4iLCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46em9vbTpjb25uZWN0OmNsaWVudGlkOjxDbGllbnRfSUQ-IiwiYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25JZCI6IjxBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbl9JRD4iLCJ1c2VySWQiOiI8VXNlcl9JRD4iLCJncm91cE51bWJlciI6MCwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9vYXV0aC56b29tLnVzIiwiYWNjb3VudElkIjoiPEFjY291bnRfSUQ-IiwibmJmIjoxNTgwMTQ3Mzk0LCJleHAiOjIwNTMxODczOTQsInRva2VuVHlwZSI6InJlZnJlc2hfdG9rZW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1ODAxNDczOTQsImp0aSI6IjxKVEk-IiwidG9sZXJhbmNlSWQiOjI2fQ.DwuqOzywRrQO2a6yp0K_6V-hR_i_mOB62flkr0_NfFdYsSqahIRRGk1GlUTQnFzHd896XDKf_FnSSvoJg_tzuQ",
   "expires_in":3599,
   "scope":"user:read"
}
```

Comment: Can you please supply your zoom config file? and screenshots of your scopes and API 's settings in zoom.dev please.

Comment: Can I see your code width /oauth/authorize petition? and yout androidmanifest?